# Android Studio JSON without Array

Tags: javascript, android, json, api, parsing

Hello my JSON Code looks so:

```
[
{
name: "Pop",
score: 968
},
{
name: "Rock",
score: 881
},
{
name: "Dance & Electronic",
score: 539
},

And so on...
```

My problem is that I do not know how to get JSON without JSONObject. I know this question has often been asked. These people do not really help me. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without JSONObject?

Comment: "I know this question has often been asked. These people do not really help me." -- please explain, **in detail**, what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. There are many options for parsing JSON arrays, such as `JSONArray`, `JsonReader`, Gson, Moshi, and Jackson.

Comment: The sample you provided is JSONArray. First, you need to parse this data into JSONArray and after that, you can iterate through each JSONObject. If you required something else please explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
   try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonStr);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = c.getString("name");
            String score = c.getInt("score");
          }
    } catch (final JSONException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, JSON Array can be extracted without going to JSON object.  But for an Android development, it is ideal to use an JSON object with the libraries